# Ruby on Rails: setting content-type in `responds_to { |f| f.any`

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails API I had a `/events` endpoint that could be called without specifying the format; no `/events.json` needed. The route:

```
resources :events, defaults: { format: :json }
```

The controller:

```
def index
  @events = get_events
  render json: @events
end
```

Now I want to respond to `/events.csv` with a CSV file, but otherwise keep the behavior unchanged. Before getting to the CSV, I add a `respond_to` block:

```
def index
  @events = get_events
  respond_to do |format|
    format.any { render json: @events }
  end
end
```

This has *almost* the same behavior as the previous approach, except that requests to `/events` now have a header `Content-Type: application/html` rather than `application/json`.

I find this surprising, given that I specify `json` in that block! But looking at the Rails source code, I see that they indeed [skip setting the Content-Type header for `any` responses](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/914caca2d31bd753f47f9168f2a375921d9e91cc/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb#L212). This makes it always set `Content-Type` to whatever the user requested, rather than matching `Content-Type` to the actual response. If someone requests XML, it returns JSON but calls it XML. If someone requests HTML, as I am in my tests without `format: :json` and when I test without the `.json` in my browser, it returns JSON but calls it HTML.

Why? And how to I override this and force the Content-Type/mime type to match the actual response?

Comment: Why not just use csv and json blocks?

Comment: Because then responses to `/events` without the `.json` don't return json anymore, instead throwing an `UnknownFormat` error. Yes, even with the `default: :json`. Solving this error a different way would also be acceptable, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Rails 6**

This issue seems to be changed in Rails 6 so that `format.any { render json: @events }` will return the `Content-Type` as `application/json` as expected

**Rails 5**

For Rails 5 a workaround can be to force change the `Content-Type` header:

```
def index
  @events = get_events
  respond_to do |format|
    format.any {
      response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
      render json: @events
    }
  end
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I had a typo. I do have the `render` in my code. It doesn't work at all without that. But with it, it still does not set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, but instead sets it to whatever the user requested. If I request XML, it renders JSON but calls it XML. I updated the original post to add more details and add the `render`.

Comment: Ok, now I better understand your question, I updated answer my answer